# Is is possible to copy the viewport to clipboard within Adobe After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, video-capture, plugins

Is there a way to copy the recent frame to clipboard to paste it in any other program?

I know there is an [exporting script from Video Copilot](http://www.videocopilot.net/blog/2010/11/copy-to-clipboard-plug-in-for-ae/) but somehow it doesn't seem to work with my version of After Effects (CC).

I get the following error message after starting AE:

> After Effects Error: Couldn't find main entry point for Comp2Clip.plugin

I am using After Effects on an iMac late 2013.

Are there any other ways to copy the viewport, or does anyone know how to fix the error?

Comment: Yes, there is a little camera icon right beside the current time indicator (in my cc version).

Comment: @poor I am aware of the snapshot thing, but how can I get it into my clipboard?

Comment: Oops, sorry then I've misread the question :) For now the only option I see is saving it as file via `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`S`, but you probably even know this...

Comment: @poor yes, but thank you anyway!:)

Comment: Unfortunately a binary, can't take a look into the source...

Comment: This version is working for me with Ae 2018: https://www.videocopilot.net/blog/2010/11/copy-to-clipboard-plug-in-for-ae/

Answer (score 1):

The free [Copy Image](http://obviousfx.com/products/copyimage/copyimage.php) plug-in should work. The plug-in is executed via Edit -> Copy image. As the [readme](http://obviousfx.com/products/copyimage/copyimage_readme.php) states,

> The image is copied as an 8bits per channel image. If the active
>   project is 16 or 32bits per channel, downsampling is performed.

Comment: Link is dead. But this worked for me with Ae 2018: https://www.videocopilot.net/blog/2010/11/copy-to-clipboard-plug-in-for-ae/

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac, you can press ctrl+cmd+shift+4, drag a box over the viewport, and the resulting image will be copied to your clipboard. This won't be a high quality file, and is dependent on the zoom/quality of your viewport.

Comment: thats not was I was looking for. What you describe is the native snapshot feature by apple. I am looking for a way to make a copy of the actual AE-Viewport with the right aspect ratio and resolution to my clipboard without having to mess arround with draggin boxes over anything.